# How and when to adjust the position of subviews?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have created the layout of my main view in a xib-file, but I want to adjust it somewhat in runtime.

I call my adjusting code from viewDidAppear. The code sets the upper left corner of a button to (0,0), but the button becomes partly hidden by the status bar!

(I call the same code when the veiw rotates and then it works fine!)

Can someone explain this?

code snippet:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL) animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    CGRect rc = CGRectMake(0, 0, 128, 128);
    [buttBack setFrame:rc];

}//viewDidAppear
```

Comment: can you please provide an exact code-snippet? thanks!

Comment: @Denis, okay I have now added the code above.

Comment: your question is not very clear. You are setting the frame to your button as 0,0 which is the top-left of your screen.

Comment: @kingthong, My problem is that the status bar hides the upper part of the button (which would be the case if the status bar was a child of the view. But my understanding is that the view and the status bar are siblings. ).

Comment: maybe your current view is not positioned at the right place. Are there any views in the view-hierarchy path to the root with negative values set in `frame` or `bounds`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put some dummy buttons at the 4 angles of your view. When runned, you wil be able to see if they disapear partially out of the screen / under the tool bar. If yes, that would explain why setting 0/0 for the origin of your button does the same thing.

Also, check that the view that contains the button you want to adjust has all its auto-adjust properties well defined. Verify also that "toolbar" simulation is ON on the main view into your XIB.

After having done that, check also that your view's H and W are correct (not too big nor loaw), but this is just for conscience, having adjusted the auto-adjust properties should deal with such errors.

Comment: I am making a universal app, so I have a MainView.xib and a Main_view-iPad.xib. When I run on the iPhone I can see all 4 dummy buttons, but on iPad the status bar hides part of the upper ones. When I edit the iPad xib-file I can see the status bar and size of the view is 768 x 1004 (i.e., 1024-20).

Comment: Okay, I found it. In the MainViewController, "Resize View From NIB" was unchecked. When I set it, the dummy buttons are placed correctly. Thanks!